# If Saturday OR Sunday then xls

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have figured out how to do a calculation if my Date Column is a Sunday.  However, I want to Add in Saturday to this formula and am struggling mightily

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(A61)=1,0,IF(H61>8.5,H61-8.5,0))
```

What I would like to have done is figure out

1. If Sunday (1) OR Saturday (6) then 0  Else IF(H61>8.5,H61-8.5,0)

**Working Formula UPDATE:**

`=IF(WEEKDAY(A3,11)>=6,0,IF(H3>=8.5,8,IF(H3<6,H3,IF(H3<8,H3-0.5,"You have an Error"))))`

also

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(A3,11)>5,0,IF(H3>8.5,H3-8.5,0))
```

Comment: I'm confused.  In your first item, you want something if it's "Sunday or Saturday" and in the 2nd, you want to treat Saturday differently and return `(H61>8.5,H61-8.5,0)`.  Can you please format this and clarify?  It would also help if you could describe your end goal in a way that makes sense.  It gives your formulas context.

Comment: I appreciate the response.  I've confused myself.  For now I just want to understand how to do the OR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can use the `OR()`:

```
=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(A10)=1,WEEKDAY(A10)=7),"Weekend","Not the Weekend")
```

So for your example:

```
=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(H61)=1,WEEKDAY(H61)=7),0,IF(H61>8.5,H61-8.5,0))
```

(you can change the weekday equality to check for `0` and `6` in your setup)

Comment: Ok, I was also able to do this for when it is not the weekend:   =IF(WEEKDAY(A3,11)>=6,0,IF(H3>=8.5,8,IF(H3<6,H3,IF(H3<8,H3-0.5,"o")))) .

Comment: NOW what I want to do is also create a formula that takes what Sam has done below.

Comment: You can nest as many as you want.  `IF(check_something, then do x, else do Y)` where `Y` can be another `IF()`.  But I can't tell what you're trying to do for the specific 0 and 6 cases, so I don't know how to write that for you.

Answer (score 4):

I am by no means an Excel expert.

As you have discovered, the Excel `IF` function takes 3 arguments:  a condition, the 'true' action, and the 'false' action.  You can chain `IF`s together.  So in your case you could do (using some pseudo code):

```
IF(day = 1, 'do the sunday thing', IF(day = 6, 'do the saturday thing', 'do the weekday thing'))
```

Its messy and there are probably better ways to implement it.. but there you go.

Comment: yeah, I've had no success with this way.  Let me try again though